# Append a number to id in jQuery to be used in jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to assign an id to variable and append `clicked_id` to that id. Then, I want to use it in `openModal()` function. My idea is like this:

**JS file**

```
var thismodal = "#myModal";

function openModal(clicked_id) {
    var trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "block";
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <img class="hover-shadow cursor card-img-top" src="images/dmc.png" id="1" onclick="openModal(this.id);currentSlide(1)" alt="">
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal"></div>
```

How do I make this work?

**EDIT**

There will be multiple instances of the HTML code. So to make them unique, I assigned numbers as id for `img` and add numbers to `myModal`. In the above instance, `myModal1` is used since the id of `img` is `1`. That's why I don't want to use `myModal1` directly.

Comment: remove `#` from `"#myModal"`, You don't need to prefix `#` when using `getElementById()` method

Comment: `document.getElementById(trueModalId)` - If you are using DOM selector, then the ID should not be prefixed with #

Comment: @zaraku27 Accept the answer also that best fit for your problem.This will help in future for others

Comment: If thats the case, then average programmers' minds think alike.

Comment: @Satpal @Krishna Thanks. I want `trueModalId` = `myModal1`. Is `var trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;` the right way to append? It still doesn't work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove # and try this:

```
var thismodal = "myModal";

function openModal(clicked_id) {
    var trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I want `trueModalId` = `myModal1`. Is `var trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;` the right way to append? It still doesn't work though when I clicked on `img`

Comment: @zaraku27 yes. Log your clicked_id on console and check if it is correct or not

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var thismodal = "#myModal";

function openModal(clicked_id) {
    var trueModalId = thismodal + clicked_id;
    $(trueModalId).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function openModal(clicked_id) {
    if($(".modal").attr('id').indexOf(clicked_id)==-1)
    {
       $(".modal").prop("id", $(".modal").attr("id")+clicked_id);
    }
    var trueModalId = $(".modal").attr('id');
    alert($(".modal").attr('id'));
    document.getElementById(trueModalId).style.display = "block";
}
```

By using the class name you can append number to your id

Comment: Is it just me or when I used `alert(trueModalId);`, I got `myModal11` instead of `myModal1`?

Comment: Whenever that function is called, the id will be appended every time, if you want to restrict after adding once, you have to make condition there if the id already have that number or not

Comment: Thanks. Your solution almost what I want. Can you please read my edit to my question? I hope it's clear.